# Язык С. Очистить оставшийся мусор в потоке stdin

Tags: c

я новичок в C. Программа очень проста: компьютер просит вас ввести firts name и second name, при этом максимальная их длина не должна быть больше 9 символов (+\0 10 символ). От переполнении в буфере поможет функция fgets. Но такая проблема: когда мы вводим в F_Name больше 9 символов, оставшиеся символы, которые не записались в F_Name, далее остаются в потоке stdin и они записываются в second name.

```
//#include "stdio.h"

//#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{

    char F_Name[10];

    char S_Name[10];

    printf("Enter your Name: ");

    fgets(F_Name, sizeof(F_Name), stdin);//Например: Dmitriyyyyyy. В F_Name 

//запишется Dmitriyyy.

    fputs(F_Name,stdout);

    printf("\n\n");

    fgets(S_Name, sizeof(S_Name), stdin);//Остальные "yyy" запишутся в S_Name, хотя по идее мы должны снова вводить строку в консоль...
    fputs(S_Name,stdout);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: ```fscanf(stdin, "%*[^\n]" );```

Answer (score 0):

Если `fgtes()` прочла все данные, то в буфере будет символ '\n'.

Если вы его там не нашли, то читайте в цикле по одному символу (`fgetc()`), пока не прочтете его. Потом переходите к чтению следующего поля.

Можно оформить такое чтение поля как функцию.